# Will records order change between two identical query in mysql without order by

Tags: mysql

The problem is I need to do pagination.I want to use order by and limit.But my colleague told me mysql will return records in the same order,and since this job doesn't care in which order the records are shown,so we don't need order by.
So I want to ask if what he said is correct? Of course assuming that no records are updated or inserted between the two queries.

Comment: Your colleague doesn't know what he is talking about. The order of the result set of an SQL query is undefined unless an ORDER BY clause is used.

Comment: If the job doesn't require any specific ordering, then you don't need `ORDER BY`, otherwise, you do need it.

Comment: @AchuthVarghese Citation please. This is not what it says in the [SQL-92 specification](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) or the [MySQL Tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/).

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Sorry for the comment (I removed it) and Thank you for correcting.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I was thinking that the order of the result is by the order of insertion when that table is indexed by PK. I suppose that's not the case always

Comment: @AchuthVarghese We know what you thought, because that's what you wrote. The question is why did you post guesswork here?

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne But what does 'undefined' mean? The goal is paging,so if there is a order between identical queries,it just dosen't make much sense to human,then it's ok to me.And in this paticular case,I only care how Mysql behives.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your query here, so I'm going to assume that it's something like the following (where `ID` is the primary key of the table):

```
select  *
from    TABLE
where   ID >= :x:
limit   100
```

If this is the case, then with MySQL you will *probably* get rows in the same order every time. This is because the only predicate in the query involves the primary key, which is a clustered index for MySQL, so is usually the most efficient way to retrieve.

However, *probably* may not be good enough for you, and if your actual query is any more complex than this one, *probably* no longer applies. Even though you may think that nothing changes between queries (ie, no rows inserted or deleted), so you'll get the same optimization plan, that is not true.

For one thing, the block cache will have changed between queries, which may cause the optimizer to choose a different query plan. Or maybe not. But I wouldn't take the word of anyone other than one of the MySQL maintainers that it won't.

Bottom line: use an `order by` on whatever column(s) you're using to paginate. And if you're paginating by the primary key, that might actually improve your performance.

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is that database engines need to handle potentially large datasets and need to care (a lot!) about performance. MySQL is never going to waste any resource (CPU cycles, memory, whatever) doing an operation that doesn't serve any purpose. Sorting result sets that aren't required to be sorted is a pretty good example of this.

When issuing a given query MySQL will try hard to return the requested data as quick as possible. When you insert a bunch of rows and then run a simple `SELECT * FROM my_table` query you'll often see that rows come back in the same order than they were inserted. That makes sense because the obvious way to store the rows is to append them as inserted and the obvious way to read them back is from start to end. However, this simplistic scenario won't apply everywhere, every time:

- Physical storage changes. You won't just be appending new rows at the end forever. You'll eventually update values, delete rows. At some point, freed disk space will be reused.
- Most real-life queries aren't as simple as  `SELECT * FROM my_table`. Query optimizer will try to leverage indices, which can have a different order. Or it may decide that the fastest way to gather the required information is to perform internal sorts (that's typical for `GROUP BY` queries).

You mention paging. Indeed, I can think of some ways to create a paginator that doesn't require sorted results. For instance, you can assign page numbers in advance and keep them in a hash map or dictionary: items within a page may appear in random locations but paging will be consistent. This is of course pretty suboptimal, it's hard to code and requieres constant updating as data mutates. `ORDER BY` is basically the easiest way. What you can't do is just base your paginator in the assumption that SQL data sets are ordered sets because they aren't; neither in theory nor in practice.

As an anecdote, I once used a major framework that implemented pagination using the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses. (I won't say the same because it isn't relevant to the question... well, dammit, it was CakePHP/2). It worked fine when sorting by ID. But it also allowed users to sort by arbitrary columns, which were often not unique, and I once found an item that was being shown in two different pages because the framework was naively sorting by a single non-unique column and that row made its way into both `ORDER BY type LIMIT 10` and `ORDER BY type LIMIT 10, 10` because both sortings complied with the requested condition.

Comment: Thank you for the reply , and I made the same order by non-unique column mistake last year too.But there is one point I can't understand.You mentioned storage,indices can affact the order.But the table doesn't change during the queries,it only gets updated at midnight,I think no one is using the system at that time.So if Mysql is using the easiest way to sort the result,does it mean the order is certain if the table doesn't change?Unless Mysql thinks random order is the easiest way?

Comment: New rows may possibly be appended at the end of the data block, but our devices don't (yet) have infinite capacity so at some point the server will reuse empty blocks or reorganise existing data to reduce fragmentation. Perhaps if you format the hard disk and reinstall the operating system from scratch every day before the midnight update you can achieve a more reproducible scheme but it isn't something I'd bet my life on.